# How to load data from own MediaWiki?

Tags: rest, etl, mediawiki

I am completely new to MediaWiki and would like to perform an initial fetch of all pages with attachments, followed by partial fetches for changed pages and attachments thereafter.

Unfortunately, I find the documentation quite unclear. What steps should I take? Do I need to configure specific parameters in the MediaWiki instance? How can I access the data?

If there are good examples?

Read API Documentation

Comment: I am afraid that your idea of wiki is inadequate, since you mention 'attachments'.